# Subquery in knex.js or direct postgresql queries in knex.js using raw or any alternative ways

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

I'm currently working in a express.js project and using knex for database migration and queries .i'm having trouble in writing the queries to get exact result which i got in postgresql (dbeaver). Below given the query which i need to convert to knex query(from a table ).Actually wants to get the count of column based on the different values of a column(applications)

---

```
select count(job_id) as total_applicants ,

(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='qualified' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b- 
a525-fad3b95fd941') as qlCount,
(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='backup' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b-a525- 
fad3b95fd941') as bckCount,
(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='interview' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b- 
a525-fad3b95fd941') as intrCount,
(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='offer' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b-a525- 
fad3b95fd941') as offrCount,
(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='screening' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b- 
a525-fad3b95fd941') as screenCount,
(select count(job_id) from applications as APPL join 
recruiter_positions as POS on POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state='rejected' and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b- 
a525-fad3b95fd941') as rejectedCount

from applications as APPL join recruiter_positions as POS on 
POS.position_id=APPL.job_id
where APPL.state notnull and POS.creator_id='e5f604be-e773-490b-a525- 
fad3b95fd941'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you are new please review the sections [ask] and [mcve].  I'm sorry but nothing in your post provides any usable information, nor even a actual question.

Comment: The query which i put here works as expected  in postgresql ,just wants to convert this to knex. Actually wants to get the count of column based on the different values of a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without converting the entire thing for you, here's how subqueries work in Knex.

Each query returns an instance of the Knex query builder, which we alias with `.as`. So it's pretty easy to build them up gradually:

```
const subquery1 = knex("foos").count("*").as("foocount");
const subquery2 = knex("bars").count("*").as("barcount");
knex.select(subquery1, subquery2).then(console.log);
```